# After Outer CV boot repair - drive disengaged

Tags: ford, transmission, focus, cv-joint

I attempted a front axle outer boot replacement on my Ford Focus Mk1 by disassembling the outer CV joint, replacing the rubber boot, and then reassembling. I backed the car out of the garage, but then the drive to the wheels disengaged. I heard a light grating noise, but got no forward or reverse drive. During fitting, I rotated the axle several times while replacing the rubber boot, the other wheel remaining  on the ground. Did I damaged something - or perhaps pulled the inner joint out from the transmission?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: @PAULSTER2 - Thanks for your welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! And thanks especially for your helpful and timely answer!!

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 - edited original post to correctly identify outer CVJ as location of repair - and likely target area of fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would bet the issue is you haven't engaged the inner CVJ into the transmission fully. You may or may not be able to check it without disassembly, but there's a chance you might. If you see any leakage at where it interfaces at the transmission, you know for sure you have an issue. You might be able to use a brass drive and hammer it home, if not, you'll have to take it apart and see if there is any wear at the tip of the splines for the inner side. The differential being open will allow it the differential to spin if one side isn't able to apply power.

Comment: I should have made clear - sorry I didn't - that I refitted the boot to the outer CV joint. But your instincts are spot on that I hadn't engaged the CVJ properly. Returned to the work today and, after removing the wheel, saw the boot had come free from the outer CVJ as you indicated, and the axle stub was out of engagement with the outer CVJ. Re-did the work, and now works fine - TY!!